# Импорт статей из Json в telegra.ph c модулем telegraph

Tags: python, json, telegram

Есть модуль telegraph
У модуля есть пример кода:

```
from telegraph import Telegraph

telegraph = Telegraph()
telegraph.create_account(short_name='1337')

response = telegraph.create_page(
    'Hey',
    html_content='<p>Hello, world!</p>'
)
print(response['url'])
```

нужен код который будет вытаскивать данные из json

```
{
    "67233": {
        "image_post": "https://test.ru/1.jpg",
        "title_post": "новая статья",
        "link_post": "https://novate.ru/blogs/240823/67233/",
        "post_dir": "bla bla bla"
    },
    "67244": {
        "image_post": "https://test.ru/1.jpg",
        "title_post": "новая статья",
        "link_post": "https://blogs/240823/67233/",
        "post_dir": "bla bla bla"
    },
```

То есть, вместо
'title' подставлять title_post и т.д
и выдавать готовые url на статьи в `telegra.ph`

Заранее благодарен за помощь

Comment: я думаю, что вам всё таки с такими задачами стоит обратиться на фриланс площадки.

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Сделал проще....написал бота который постит в telegra.ph